# Convert objects to numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file and it has a column full of numbers. These numbers can be formatted as 45.11 , 1,234.33, 122.33, 10,222.22 etc.

Right now they are showing up as objects in my data frame, and i need to convert them to numeric. I have tried:

```
df['Value'].astype(str).astype(float)
```

But am getting errors like this:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,054.43'

Does anyone know how to solve this for the weirdly formatted numbers?

Comment: What does the commas the your datafile represent? Does the comma represent a period to assist the reader so 1,234.33 is equal to 1234.33?

Comment: No that did not work, and yes they represent 1234.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should make the job

```py
vals={'Value': ["45.11" , "1,234.33", "122.33", "10,222.22"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)

df.Value = df.Value.apply(lambda x: x.replace(",", "")).astype(float)

print(df.Value)
```

output

```
0       45.11
1     1234.33
2      122.33
3    10222.22
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I just tried this, and when i do df.dtypes its still showing as a object

Comment: @SeanK22 I believe they meant `df.Value = df.Value.apply(lambda x: x.replace(",", "")).astype(float)`.

Comment: @Axe319 yes it is correct I'll update the answer